# What is the difference between %[^\n] and %[^\n]s?

Tags: c, string

Why some writers use `%[^\n]s` specifier instead of `%[^\n]`? Which one is correct?

Comment: Correct to do what?

Comment: It's about the same as the difference between `"%ds"` and `"%d"`. The first expects an integer followed by an actual `s` in the input, the second doesn't expects the `s`. However, both are proper formats, and how "correct" any is depends on the input being parsed.

Comment: This may sound incredibly arrogant, but "some writers" don't know their C as well as they think they do.

Comment: Try to run some code that uses both format strings and look at the results ... That is a good way to learn !!! :)

Comment: Like @StoryTeller said, some people seem to think that the `[]` character group format specifier is a modifier to the `s` format specifier, and not a specifier in its own right. This might also *work*, as long as there is no actual `s` trailing the converted characters, and/or they don't check the scanning function's return vaule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read in a sequence of non-newline characters, `%[^\n]` is correct.

The `%[` format specifier to `scanf` will accept any following characters until a `]` is encountered.  If the first given character is `^`, then it accepts characters **not** in this list.  The characters that are read are then placed in the given `char *` parameter.

`%[^\n]s` is the above format specifier *followed by a literal `'s'`*.  The `s` is *not* part of the `%[` format specifier.  So this will read characters until it encounters a newline and put those characters in the given `char *`, then it will attempt to read an `s` character which it doesn't find because a newline is next.

Comment: ... and so the two are work-alikes when they appear at the end of the format string.  In that sense, they might both be correct in a given situation.  Nevertheless, the trailing `s` should not be used, as it produces just the sort of confusion that the OP expressed, and because it builds bad habits that are prone to biting back when a `%[` directive is used other than at the end of the format.